# Saving and updating configuration settings in Java application

Tags: java, ini

I have designed a Java application and I want to save its last window state and some other settings like date format. I currently save window state to "config.ini" file and it works fine for this code.

```
    private void saveConfig() {
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();

            properties.setProperty("windowstate", String.valueOf(this.getExtendedState()));

            properties.store(new FileOutputStream("./data/config.ini"), null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

But I want to save some other settings too. For that can I update individual parameters of this config.ini file? (Currently there is only "windowstate", in case there is something like date format, last used email address etc...)

My current file is like this

```
#Sun Jul 07 22:19:35 IST 2013
windowstate=0
```

E.g. If config.ini file is like this

```
#Sun Jul 07 22:19:35 IST 2013
windowstate=0
dateformat=yyyy-MM-dd
lastmailaddress=abcd@mail.com
```

can I update only "lastmailaddress" without affecting others? and how?
Currently my code is overwriting this file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a new `Properties` every time and add just `windowstate` to it. How could it know about anything else?

You have to:

1. load the properties from the file
2. add and/or modify settings
3. save the properties to the same file

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("D:/raman/abnconfig.ini");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(in);
in.close();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:/raman/abnconfig.ini");
props.setProperty("HSMLUNAPWD", "AUS");
props.store(out, null);
out.close();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) Just a couple of comments: a) please learn how to format code (can be tempting in the beginning, as I remember from my first days here :-) b) adding a bit of explanation to a code snippet helps future reader to understand the solution better